# Can an outfield player substitute for a goalkeeper?

Tags: rules, football, goalkeeper

In the game of soccer, I was wondering, if I were a player on the outfield, would it be possible for me to substitute for the goalkeeper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If you can't change an injured goalkeeper, what can you do?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/if-you-cant-change-an-injured-goalkeeper-what-can-you-do) It's not the *exact* same question, but the answer addresses your query.

Comment: This is not the same question. My question is in regards to allowing a field player walk on for the goalie.

Comment: Then, the law quoted in the first answer there is clear: there must be a goalkeeper. If you mean switching the goalkeeper role between players already on the field, that is also covered. If you mean a substitution of any other kind, you'll need to clarify by editing this question.